# Joomla Who is online auto refresh

Tags: jquery, joomla

There is a core module that shows the online users, if you are already in the page and a new user login you will not see him until you refresh the page. I want it to show the user without refreshing the hole page. I was thinking to make particular div to refresh with interval.

```
<div id="cusers">
<?php $i = 0; foreach($names as $name) : ?>

        <?php echo "<span style='color:". $colors[$i % 6]."'>".$name->username."</span>"; $i += 1;?></a>,

<?php endforeach;  ?></div>
```

In the above code make the #cusers to autorefresh every 5 secs for example with ajax. Any ideas how to achieve that?

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
 jQuery('#cusers').html('<?php $i = 0; foreach($names as $name) : ?><a  href="index.php/forum/profile/<?php echo (int) $name->userid; ?>"><?php echo "<span>".$name->username."</span>"; $i += 1;?></a>,<?php endforeach;  ?>');     

}, 3000);
</script>
```

This does the rerun the script but it does not get new info from the database sessions, so it simply shows the same users from the first time I loaded the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had no time so I did a little bit of an "external" solution... Here it is:

the script for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
 jQuery('#cusers').load('online.php');     

}, 3000);
</script>
```

Above I load every 3 secs the online.php to div with id cusers (you have to create such a div in the module or declare above another div that exists already).

the online.php:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from prefix_session WHERE guest=0");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {

echo $row['username'];

  }
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

You might wanna connect to database through joomla framework, thats your choice. I found this way easier cause of the possibility to update joomla without loosing this functionality.

This offcource could be made to a module but I have no time for that now, till I find some to make one hope this helps someone else too :)

Comment: Changing your MySQL password forces you to update passwords in multiple places.